# Triangulating a convex Catalan Numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:** Let $t_n$ denote the number of ways of triangulating a convex $(n+2)$-gon by drawing $n-1$ diagonals. Show that $t_n=C_n$ as follows. Label the vertices $1,\ldots,n+2$, and consider the triangle containing edge 12. If it contains vertex $r$ as its third vertex, in how many ways can the remaining two parts of the interior of the $(n+2)$-gon be triangulated? Deduce that $t_n=\sum{t_it_j}$ where summation is over all pairs $i,j$ with $i+j=n-1$.

I begin with the suggested shapes but then I'm lost. I have no idea how to begin! Any hints or answers?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the triangle $\triangle ABP$ is part of a triangulation of the polygon; the rest of the triangulation must consist of a triangulation of the left polygon and a triangulation of the right polygon. If there are $\ell$ possible triangulations of the left polygon and $r$ of the right polygon, they can be combined in $\ell r$ ways to produce $\ell r$ different triangulations of the big polygon; those $\ell r$ triangulations are precisely the ones that include $\triangle ABP$. The suggestion in the problem is that you sum those numbers as $P$ moves around the polygon from $Q$ to $R$. How do you know what $\ell$ and $r$ are? That’s your induction hypothesis.

[image]